# Client side url validation script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate, client-side

I'm looking help finding JavaScript or jQuery script to properly format a URL when user type in a textbox. This is an ASP.NET site

For example, if user typed in www.stackoverflow.com/something, i need a script to automatically correct it to http://www.stackoverflow.com/something when the textbox has lost focus or on validation, on the client side.

Thanks

Comment: khalid, what type of validations your are looking for , is it just prepending or http?? or anything else

Comment: [Here](http://www.robsearles.com/2010/05/27/jquery-validate-url-adding-http/) is a solution in jQuery . hope it helps

Comment: i need to prepend http:// if user forgot it. Validation is handled already.